# computer doesn't show in dns but can ping

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, dns, group-policy

what is this error? i am going to update group policy. Unable to find any Issue.

```
C:\Users\administrator.TOROID>gpupdate /force
Updating Policy...

User policy could not be updated successfully. The following errors were encountered:

The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows attempted to retrieve new Group Policy settings for this user or computer. Look in the details tab for error codeand description. Windows will automatically retry this operation at the next refresh cycle. Computers joined to the domain must have proper name resolution and network connectivity to a domain controller for discovery of new Group Policy objects and settings. An event will be logged when Group Policy is successful.
Computer policy could not be updated successfully. The following errors were encountered:

The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not determine the computer account to enforce Group Policy settings. This may be transient. Group Policy settings, including computer configuration, will not be enforced for this computer.

To diagnose the failure, review the event log or run GPRESULT /H GPReport.html from the command line to access information about Group Policy results.
```

Comment: Check whether ur active directory server or group policy server is pingable. Make sure any windows updates are stuck.. if yes clear it. Run resop.msc.. u can see the set of policy which is applied. In which group policy it's hunging up with error also

Comment: AD is pingable. i took a gpresult as  html page and it shows group policy link is down. I tried to rename and computer add domain to again possible to add network also. but it doesn't show in AD computers

Comment: What is the exact error it's showing in report. Did u run resop.msc??

Comment: When you run gpupdate meanwhile u check in event viewer also.. what is exact error on even viewer

Comment: EVENT ID 1097 and 1030. i have pasted error. i used gpupdate /force command to update to group policy.

Comment: Are u getting ip from dhcp. If yes run this commands Ipconfig /flushdns. Ipconfig /release and ipconfig / renew Try to disable ipv6. Check ur date and time of the pc. Run w32tm /resync. And restart your pc.. try to update once again..

Comment: Techie Gossip, Everything done. But no good result. now i am installing windows again.